# Convert table into JSON

Tags: python, json, bash

I am triying to convert a table (in csv) into JSON format.

**Input** (input.csv)

```
id,v1,v2,v3
ab,1,2,3
cd,4,5,6
ef,7,8,9
```

**Expected output**

```
[
{"id": "ab", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": 1}, {"var": "v2", "value": 2}, {"var": "v3", "value": 3}]},
{"id": "cd", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": 4}, {"var": "v2", "value": 5}, {"var": "v3", "value": 6}]},
{"id": "ef", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": 7}, {"var": "v2", "value": 8}, {"var": "v3", "value": 9}]}
]
```

So far, I have writen a loop for this, and that works

```
import csv 
import json 

def make_json(csv_path, json_path): 
      
    V1 = {}
    V2 = {}
    V3 = {}
    V = {}
    Vlist = []
      
    with open(csv_path) as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
        
        for rows in csvReader: 
            
            V["id"] = rows["id"]
            
            V1["var"] = "v1"
            V1["value"] = rows['v1']
            V2["var"] = "v2"
            V2["value"] = rows['v2']
            V3["var"] = "v3"
            V3["value"] = rows['v3']
            
            V["vars"] = [V1, V2, V3]
            Vlist.append(V)
            
    json_string = json.dumps(Vlist)
    
    with open(json_path, 'w') as jsonf: 
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(json_string))
```

```
make_json("input.csv", "my.json")
```

**my.json**

```
[{"id": "ef", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": "7"}, {"var": "v2", "value": "8"}, {"var": "v3", "value": "9"}]}, {"id": "ef", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": "7"}, {"var": "v2", "value": "8"}, {"var": "v3", "value": "9"}]}, {"id": "ef", "vars": [{"var": "v1", "value": "7"}, {"var": "v2", "value": "8"}, {"var": "v3", "value": "9"}]}]
```

However, my real csv is big with dozen columns (unstructured column name. not v1, v2, v3). So I am looking for more clever solution. Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: `import json` would be the best place to start. `pandas` would be easiest to convert between the file types (see my answer below)

Comment: Does your input file actually have all that ascii art around fields, or is it really just csv? If the latter, use the actual format.

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filename.csv').to_json('filename.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed this link: https://datatofish.com/csv-to-json-string-python/

The relevant part probably is this:

```
import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_csv (import_file_path)
...
read_file.to_json (export_file_path)
```

There are also lots of online tools, if you only need to do it once.
(such as : https://csvjson.com/csv2json